# Question about Hermitian Symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A$ is a Hermitian symmetric n x n matrix with complex entries having all of its eigenvalues lying inside the interval, (-1, 1). Is $A^3 + Id$ always a positive definite matrix? My hunch says yes, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What are the eigenvalues of $A^3+I$?

Comment: got it, thanks!